# Adding ToggleButton value to an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, swing, netbeans, togglebutton

I need to create a lottery program that will allow user to select 4 numbers [(image of the buttons here)](http://prntscr.com/e9zcvu)
 which then should be inputed into an array, I cannot get the array to fill fully, I have tried different versions of adding an int into array and I just can't seem to find the right one..

```
int hold;
int userNumbers[] = new int[3];
public lotteryGUI() {
    initComponents();

}
 private void twentyoneActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
hold = 21;
hold += userNumbers[0];
}                                         

private void nineActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
hold = 9;
userNumbers[0]= hold + userNumbers[0];    
}                                    

private void oneActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
hold = 1;
userNumbers[0] = userNumbers[0] + hold ;
}
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(userNumbers));
}
```

This is just a sample with 3 buttons, As you can probably tell the output i  get is (10,0,0).

@edit
I have contacted my lecturer about this project and I received a little hint. I am supposed to add ActionListener and if the button is checked I am supposed to add it to an array. Not really sure how to do that, I'm going to look at some tutorials and edit this post if necessary

Comment: Consider creating the smallest program that demonstrates your problem, say a compilable and runnable program with a very simple hand-coded (not NetBeans generated) GUI and your array with your best attempt to solve the main issue. I'm essentially asking you to create and post here with your question a valid [mcve]. Also consider explaining your problem in greater detail -- anything that you can do to improve our understanding of your problem will improve the answers that you might get.

Comment: I'm currently in second year in college, we have not learned how to create jframeform by hand. My question is if it is possible to fill an array using Toggle Buttons, and if so then where did I go wrong in my code.

Comment: You can learn to create JFrame by hand with the Swing Tutorials and the [Swing Info link](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info) will get you to those tutorials. As for "where did I go wrong", again, I can tell much better if you create and post that very small MCVE program as linked to in my first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would hate to hard code it, but it is really up to you to figure out how to do that for 28 buttons. Here is example for 1 button:

```
int counter = 0;
int[] userNumbers = new int[3];

public lotteryGUI() {
    initComponents();

    JButton number1 = new JButton("1");
    JButton number2 = new JButton("2"); 

    number1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            userNumbers[counter] = 1;
            counter = counter + 1;
            if (counter == 3)
                // disable all buttons and display result maybe?
        }
    }

    // ... the rest 27 buttons maybe?
}
```

Comment: There are 28 different numbers, every Toggle Button is one of them. The user needs to pick 4 numbers that should be stored in array called userNumbers. My problem is that I do not know how to store user choice into that array. I cannot do it the way you suggested because I don't know what number will the user pick and in what order. I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: @hDDen So (an ugly solution) but you can create an event for each one of your buttons and then you know which button was clicked. But based on your questions I suspect you are *very* new to programming and you really need somebody to sit down with you. You won't get this kind of help on StackOverflow. This is not newbie training site

Comment: I have contacted my lecture about this project and I received a little hint. I am supposed to add ActionListener and if the button is checked I am supposed to add it to an array. Not really sure how to do that, I'm going to look at some tutorials and edit this post if necessary

Comment: I am receiving an error on the line: 
`userNumbers.add(1);` 
Stating: "Cannot find symbol, method add(int) in the location variable userNumebrs of type int[]"

Comment: Because I changed it on line 1. do you have to use `Array`? `ArrayList<int> userNumbers = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: I **have** to user `Array` indeed.